# How to install gtk on OSX for use with g++/gcc compiler

Tags: c++, c, macos, gcc

I already asked this question [at apple.stackexchange.com](https://apple.stackexchange.com/posts/111239/edit), but I was told it was the wrong place for this question - so I will ask it here, as I was suggested to do.

At my university we got the task to implement a c-program which has a GTK-GUI. The GTK-GUI is already implemented, we just have to implement a algorithm which hands it some data.

I already got gcc/g++ working. But when i try to compile the project the compiler returns the error, that it does not find the gtk:

```
fatal error: 'gtk/gtk.h' file not found
#include <gtk/gtk.h>
         ^
```

**So my question is:**
How do I install gtk on OSX Mavericks for using it with gcc/g++ compiler?

My setup: MacBook Pro Retina Mid 2012 with OSX Mavericks. Homebrew is installed and working if it could be useful for the installation.

(Of course the Apple Command Line Developer Tools are installed)

Comment: Fix your include path if `gtk` headers aren't available in the default include path.

Comment: @devnull I'm afraid I don't know how to do that.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

I finally solved the Problem. tojanfoe suggested in a comment the link http://www.hardcoded.net/devlogs/20120426 which turned out to not be helpful.

This is how i solved it:

1.a) Installation of  GTK+ 2.x:

```
brew install gtk+
```

1.b) Installation of GTK+ 3.x:

You can install gtk+ 3.x via home brew too if you need that, but the 2.x version is enough for my purposes. The command would be:

```
brew install gtk+3
```

2.)
But after the installation I had the problem, that cairo could not be found. So i solved it this way:

```
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/local/Cellar/cairo/1.12.16/lib/pkgconfig/
```

3.)
Then the compiler said it could not find the package 'xcb-shm', required by 'cairo'. This can be solved this way:

```
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/X11/lib/pkgconfig
```

After this command the compiler worked as expected.

Comment: where is gtk.h located on your system after install?

Comment: @user391339 gtk.h is in  `/usr/local/Cellar/gtk+/2.24.31_1/include/gtk-2.0/gtk/gtk.h` found using `pkg-config  --cflags gtk+-2.0`

Comment: some GTK2 apps require: `brew install gtkglext`

Comment: @user391339  At the end of the installation, it shows the gtk path. Now you do: find /usr/local/Cellar/gtk+3 -name gtk.h

Answer (score 3):

You can download precompiled Gtk2 Framework from: http://r.research.att.com
http://r.research.att.com/libs/GTK_2.24.17-X11.pkg,
or
http://r.research.att.com/libs/GTK_2.18.5-X11.pkg

And Gtk3 Framework from: http://www.tarnyko.net/dl/gtk.htm