# GTK compilation on mac returns several errors

Tags: c, macos, gcc, gtk, gtk4

I have been trying to get started on GTK for Mac. I followed the [installation steps](https://www.gtk.org/docs/installations/macos/) and ran the [hello-world program](https://www.gtk.org/docs/getting-started/hello-world/). I keep getting this error with gcc, though. Running

```bash
gcc $(pkg-config --cflags gtk4) -o hello-world-gtk hello-world-gtk.c $(pkg-config --libs gtk4)
```

returns the following errors:

```c
Package gtk4 was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `gtk4.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'gtk4' found
Package gtk4 was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `gtk4.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'gtk4' found
hello-world-gtk.c:1:10: fatal error: 'gtk/gtk.h' file not found
#include <gtk/gtk.h>
         ^~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
```

I found a [similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20098862/how-to-install-gtk-on-osx-for-use-with-g-gcc-compiler) here, but the user says they already have gcc/g++ working. I don't.

Any ideas? I ran the installation script included in the installation steps and nothing changes.

Also, I have tried replacing the line

```c
#include <gtk/gtk.h>
```

with

```c
#include <gtk-2.0/gtk/gtk.h>
```

I then get this error:

```bash
Package gtk4 was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `gtk4.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'gtk4' found
Package gtk4 was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `gtk4.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'gtk4' found
In file included from hello-world-gtk.c:1:
/usr/local/include/gtk-2.0/gtk/gtk.h:32:10: fatal error: 'gdk/gdk.h' file not
      found
#include <gdk/gdk.h>
         ^~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
```

If I add the flags `-I/usr/include/gtk-2.0 -lgtk2.0` to my compile statement, I get the same error.

Comment: In Linux, one can execute the command "pkg-config --list-all" to list out all of the packages.  If your Mac has that command, you might run that and see for sure if "gtk4" is in the list.

Comment: @NoDakker I found several different `gtk`s on the list, but none which were `gtk4`. I followed all the instructions on the site for installation. What am I missing?

Comment: Not sure what you might have missed.  Linux is a bit different from Macs.